# Does C# XMLSerializer handle special character escaping by default?

Tags: c#, .net, escaping, xmlserializer

I have inherited a legacy C# utility that extracts from a database and writes out XML. A question has been asked whether the utility can handle strings with embedded double quotes and various characters that need to be escaped.

My experience with C# is limited. I found that the utility uses code like the following:

```
//write out the xml file
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AcmeData), "urn:acme.com:imaging");

XmlSerializerNamespaces nameSpaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
nameSpaces.Add("is", "urn:acme.com:imaging");
nameSpaces.Add("dg", "urn:acme.com:SchemaTypes");
nameSpaces.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.None;
serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, folio, nameSpaces);
```

Studying this page, I cannot seem to find the information. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.7.2

Is it true that XmlSerializer handles escaping characters by default?

Comment: Yes; XmlSerializer will not produce illegal XML.

Comment: @SLaks Thank you.